# Convert string (EditText input) to Long in android

Tags: android, numbers

Android 2.3.3

Program: calculator

I have a `EditText` that takes a string (ex: `100+1.20+45+...`)

When I try to parse `1.20` to long, using `Long.parseLong(1.20)`, 
I get the following error.

```
12-07 14:28:32.902: E/AndroidRuntime(771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 14:28:32.902: E/AndroidRuntime(771): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 1.20
12-07 14:28:32.902: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:353)
12-07 14:28:32.902: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:344)
12-07 14:28:32.902: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:311)
```

I tried `Long.valueOf()` as well, but as I read somewhere, `Long.valueOf()` returns a `Long` object, where as `Long.parseLong()` returns `long` value. So, I hope what i trying to do is correct.

I read all possible questions regarding this, but couldn't get it solved. Can someone help me out.

Code in case you need it...

```
long result=0;
String expression = editText1.getText().toString();
String[] strArrayExpression2 = expression.split("\\+");


for(int i=0; i<strArrayExpression2.length;i++)
{
  result += Long.parseLong(strArrayExpression2[i]);
}
```

Answer :::
Use Float.parseFloat() or Double.parseDouble() as per the requirement.

Comment: `1.20` **is not** a long, see `Math.round` or something similar

Comment: Can you post the code for us?

Comment: The thing is I have to add all the numbers in the input. For ex, 100+1.20+45 should give me 146.20, and round will only give me 146, which is not the correct value.

Comment: then use `Double` or `Float` which handle floating point

Comment: oops!!! I almost forgot there is such thing as Float. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `double` instead of `long`:

```
String strInput = edittext.getText().toString();
double d = Double.parseDouble(strInput );
```

**// Edit**

```
double result=0;
String expression = editText1.getText().toString();
String[] strArrayExpression2 = expression.split("\\+");


for(int i=0; i<strArrayExpression2.length;i++)
{
  result += Double.parseDouble(strArrayExpression2[i]);
}
```

Comment: how you convert `100+1.20+45+...` sting to any number?

Answer (score 2):

use this:

`String str = edtText.getEditableText.toString();`

`Float l = Float.parseFloat(str)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that could be a problem with your devices locale. In some countries '.' and ',' don't habe the same meaning. For example the english written number 1.20 would 1,20 here in germany. Same value, different notation.